# Yandex Map Api (динамическое перещение/обновление объектов на карте)

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть yandex карта.
Имеется функция, которая с каждым интервалом времени возвращает массив, полученный с сервера.
Массив представляет собой структуру, состоящую из [x,y,ID-элемента],[...],[...].
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой верный и правильный способ выбрать, для того, чтобы в цикле производить обновление маркеров на карте. Т.е. координаты элементов могут измениться, а также могут и вовсе пропасть.

Comment: Как вариант использовать 2 массив с указателями на маркеры, при получении данных сравнивать координаты, если изменились- перерисовывать.

Comment: Да, это верный способ. Но по какому параметру, можно сравнивать метки между собой, - ту, что на карте с элементом и ту которая пришла с сервера. Изначально есть ID с сервера, но можно ли присвоить ID маркеру, для дальнейшего получения этого объекта для сравнения?

Comment: Нет- добавьте доп свойство для объекта в массиве- {x, y, ID-элемента, ID-маркера}.

Comment: Спасибо, да добавлю доп. поле. Но не могу найти пример/способ, позволяющий присвоить ID маркеру и получить его для операции сравнения.

Comment: Не знаю как у яндекса, у гугла при установке маркера `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({` возвращается идентификатор маркера.
Возможно `new ymaps.Placemark([55.826479, 37.487208]` тоже возвращает подобный идентификатор.

Comment: А в чём проблема просто удалить все текущие объекты и добавить на карту снова? Если это лишь голые координаты и ID, быстрее будет разом удалять все старые и добавлять новые объекты, а не выполнять специфические операции сравнения/фильтрации/изменения и прочие.